# Redirect all pages to new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all the pages of my website to a new domain with a redirect. I've managed to get it working on domain level but not on the subpages.

So olddomain.com redirects to newdomain.com but olddomain.com/contact doesn't redirect to newdomain.com. It still shows the old domain.

I've used multiple rewrites rules but none of them seem to works. Any help is much appreciated.

This is the code that I'm using right now in my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^racentegenkanker\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.racentegenkanker\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/againstcancer\.nl\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a full website redirection, you can use this (entire) .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://againstcancer.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT**

For two domains running side by side, with one redirecting the other :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} racentegenkanker\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://againstcancer.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: If I use that redirect I get an error telling me that there are too many redirects. Even after removing the default Wordpress redirect.

Comment: Please check if this `.htaccess` is placed on your **old** domain. Indeed, if you're using it on your new domain, you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: Ah I see, but but there is no 'old' domain. They are both available and active at the same time. Both domains are available but everything should be rewritten to the againstcancer.nl domain.

Comment: I see, I edited my answer, taking into account you're using Wordpress.

Comment: You're welcome, you were pretty near. Just remember the `[L]` tag stop the `.htaccess` reading when a rule match. Then you must be careful of your rules order.